# M/M/1 Queue with probability of new customer leaving

Tags: pr.probability, stochastic-processes

I'm looking at a M/M/1 queue system and trying to show that $\{M_t\}_{t\geq}0$, the number of clients in the system, is a birth-death process. In the simplest of cases this is true if $\lambda_i = \lambda$ and $\mu_i = \mu \forall i$. In the current situation we're adding the non-trivial probability that a new client decides to leave depending on the number of people currently in the system.

For instance if at time $t$ we have $M_t=n$ then a client arriving in the system would decide to stay with a probability $p_n=\frac{1}{1+n}$. This modifies the regular arrival rate (which would normally be $\lambda$) although the average service time remains the same ($\frac{1}{\mu}$) but I'm not sure how.

Any tips on how to tackle this situation? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are interested in a model with "balking". See e.g.

> János Sztrik, Basic Queueing Theory, Chapter 2.2., p. 25-29, [link](http://irh.inf.unideb.hu/~jsztrik/education/16/SOR_Main_Angol.pdf)

I assume that the probability you gave was not meant to be a probability of leaving but rather of staying.

Comment: You're right, the probability is of staying. I'll edit my first post. Thanks for the pdf and the term "balking" it'll make the rest of my search for info a lot easier (the pdf also contains quite a few things I needed to look over as well)